# Azure SDK 2.4 installation failed to install the Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, installation

Using the Azure SDK installer 2.4 failed to install the azure storage emulator with the following error on the log:

```
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.3.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:  Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Configuration.StorageEmulatorConfigCache' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'enable'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 104)
CAQuietExec:     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
CAQuietExec:     at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
CAQuietExec:     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
CAQuietExec:     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
CAQuietExec:     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
CAQuietExec:     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Configuration.StorageEmulatorUpdatableConfiguration.GetConfigurationSection(String name)
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Configuration.StorageEmulatorConfigCache..cctor()
CAQuietExec:     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Configuration.StorageEmulatorConfigCache.get_Configuration()
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Initialization..ctor(Boolean forceCreate, Boolean autodetect, String server, String sqlInstance)
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.InitCommand.RunCommand()
CAQuietExec:     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Program.Main(String args)
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: CAQuietExec Failed
```

Looking at the machine.config line found the 'enable' attribute but I am not sure why this would be a problem. 
Here is the machine.config line

```
            <section name="processModel" type="System.Web.Configuration.ProcessModelSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineOnly" allowLocation="false" enable="true" requestQueueLimit="15000"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue , the following is how i fixed the issue.

1. Uninstall old Windows Azure Storage emulator , via add/remove programs. In case if you are not able uninstall then use FixItnow to uninstall http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en

2.Once the old emulator is gone , you should be able to install the new storage emulator.

Give it a try and let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Krishna for your reply unfortunately I had already uninstalled the previous emulators but I am still having the same problem

Comment: <section name="processModel" type="System.Web.Configuration.ProcessModelSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineOnly" allowLocation="false"/> This is what i have in my machine.config

Comment: In addition look into C:\Users\<YourUserName>\WAStorage*.*. Clean them out and see if it helps to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the previous post there was a posted machine.config that gave me the answer to this question.

After looking and comparing your **Machine.config** from a successful install I found that the one that worked did not have the "**enable**" attribute nor the "**requestQueueLimit**" defined.

I removed those 2 attributes while installing and it worked. I am not sure how the installer works but it apparently does not have all the definitions for all the "processModel" element in the machine.config.

I hope there is someone out there that knows why this would be an issue and why this fix works.

Comment: I also found that if you go back to having the attributes the emulator will fail.